# How to plot the Fourier transform of the Dirac function?

Tags: sympy

How to plot the Fourier transform of I(x) that includes the Dirac function (defined in the code)?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sympy import DiracDelta
import numpy as np

a1 = 1.6
a2 = 0.6
x1 = 1 
x2 = 5

x_start = 0
x_end   = 6

x = np.linspace(x_start, x_end, 1000)

I = a1 * DiracDelta(x-x1) + a2 * DiracDelta(x-x2)
FurI = ???????

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))

plt.xlim(x_start, x_end)
y1 = 0
plt.ylim(y1,1.2)

plt.plot(x, FurI, c='navy')

ax.set_xlabel(r'$x$')
ax.set_ylabel(r'$I$')

plt.show()
```

The desired result is a period function.

Comment: You understand how the Dirac delta function is defined, yes? How exactly are you expecting the plot to look?

Comment: Is there something that contradicts the definition? I expect two peaks in the plot.

Comment: You can't see these peaks, because they are infinitely "narrow" and infinitely "high" (actually the value is undefined at that point, only the integral across it is defined). Anyway, you should try to test exactly which operation on that line causes a problem for Sympy, and then also try reading the documentation for `DiracDelta`.

Comment: Thanks, I have editted the question.